# MYSQL trigger to select * from table and check each value and update other table

Tags: mysql, triggers

i am having where one of my table has a trigger which will execute after update of the table to check if the values of the fields for the id values updated, are true if any of value is false update other table with false else with true.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE
TRIGGER users_lookups
AFTER UPDATE ON UsersValidations
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM UsersValidations where id=New.id;
/* MY SCENARIO 
{   HOW to do this portion

  if(UsersValidations.value1 =="true" and UsersValidations.value2=="true" and UsersValidations.value3=="true")
    {
         update table2 set myvalue="true" where id=New.id;
    }
    else
    {
         update table2 set myvalue="false" where id=New.id;
    }

}*/

END$$
```

Comment: @JeremyGoodell how do i write the commented portion

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to query the table since the trigger already knows the values of the row being operated on. Just use the New construct provided by the trigger.

Here is an updated version of your trigger, although I don't have mysql on this computer so I can't validate the syntax. Consider this pseudocode of sorts.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE
TRIGGER users_lookups
AFTER UPDATE ON UsersValidations
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

  if(New.value1 =="true" and New.value2=="true" and New.value3=="true")
    {
         update table2 set myvalue="true" where id=New.id;
    }
    else
    {
         update table2 set myvalue="false" where id=New.id;
    }


END$$
```

Comment: not necessarily, but it should be easily translateable into such.